# Droplist from array nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, ejs

I want to create a button that makes appair a droplist. The content of this droplist is passed to my EJS through an array from my DB.

Here is what I've got so far :

EJS :

```html
  <form class="" action="/post" method="post">


// some inputs here

<div class="container">
  <p>Select a related list of keywords :</p>
  <div class="container1">
    <button class="add_form_field1">keywords &nbsp;
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"> + </span>
    </button>
</div>
</div class="container">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

// some more code not relevant here, and my script for the magic to (not) append :

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field1");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div>  <select name="role">          <% if(typeof keywords == 'object' && 
keywords.length > 0){ %><% for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {%><option 
value='keywords[j]'>keywords[j]</option>  <% } %> <% } %> </>select>  <a href="#" 
class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add selectbox
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
  });
  </script>
```

This is my app-related code :

```
app.get('/post', isLoggedIn, (req, res) =>{

db.collection('keywords').find().toArray()
.then(results => {
res.render('test.ejs', {keywords:results})
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))
})
```

The main problem is the button in container1 "posts" the form directly without doing anything script-related.

Could someone help ? :)

EDIT : changed the contnent of the div class"container1" to:

```
div class="container1">
    <select name="keyword[]"><% for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {%><option value='<%=keywords[j]._id%>'><%=keywords[j].keyword%></option>  <% } %> </select>
    <button type="button" role="button" class="add_form_field1">Add keywords &nbsp;
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"> + </span>
    </button>
```

the displaying part of the first droplist works like a charm, and so does the submit button (the right one) but still facing issues with the button whose supposed to make appair more droplists ..

**SOLVED SOLUTION :**

thanks to @Kinglish
SCRIPT:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var max_fields = 10;
      var wrapper = $(".container1");
      var add_button = $(".add_form_field1");

      var x = 1;
      (add_button).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
          x++;
          wrapper.append('<div>  <select name="keyword[]"> <% for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {%><option value=<%=keywords[j]._id%>><%=keywords[j].keyword%></option>  <% } %> </select>  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
        } else {
          alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
      });
      wrapper.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
      })
    });
  </script>
```

EJS:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Select a related list of keywords :</p>
  <div class="container1">
    <button type="button" role="button" class="add_form_field1">Add keywords &nbsp;
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"> + </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try correcting this typo and see if it helps: `</>select>` - also `add_button = $(".add_form_field1");`, then `$(add_button)` - you don't have to double up the `$(`. Also, when you click the button, do you see an error in the console for a second before the form submits?

Comment: I did not spot the typo, thanks ! No, I don't have any error in the console. Now the submit button behaves well, but the other one stays idle....

Comment: stays idle? Are you still having issues with the code?

Comment: Yes, What I mean is that the "Keyword" does not do any thing.. I would like it to display an list of item from an array. on standalone, the droplist bar code is : '<select name="keyword"><% if(typeof keywords == 'object' && keywords.length > 0){ %><% for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {%><option value='keywords[j]'><%=keywords[j].keyword%></option>  <% } %> <% } %> </select>' and this works fine. Now I would like, for exemple, that cliking three times the keyword button it would make appair 3 droplists from whose you could choose 3 differnts values to post

Comment: another typo: `<option value='<%=keywords[j]%>'>`

Comment: @VortextSensei - does that multi-button = multi-select list thing not work? It looks like it should...

Comment: It doesn't, I've tried it on edge and chrome.. What I dont get is that the same code works for another of my projects, I'v just changed what's inside  '$(wrapped).append()' to fit my needs ...

Comment: I found other typos and discovered why it's not working for you. I turned it into an answer. Let me know if that doesn't solve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were lots of little typos which were causing JS errors, preventing the code from executing and causing a form submit. Please review the following and update your code from it. I removed the asp loop so this could be testable, but you can easily put it back in

```js
// some more code not relevant here, and my script for the magic to (not) append :

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field1");

  var x = 1;
  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      wrapper.append('<div><select name="role"><option>test</option></select><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add selectbox
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });
  wrapper.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="/post" method="post">

  <div class="container">
    <p>Select a related list of keywords :</p>
    <div class="container1">
      <button class="add_form_field1">keywords &nbsp;
    <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;"> + </span>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, I've tryed you answer, worked like a charm, but the moment I change your _'<div><select name="role"><option>test</option></select><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'_ by my_ '<div>  <select name="keyword[]"> <% for(var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {%><option value='<%=keywords[j]._id%>'><%=keywords[j].keyword%></option>  <% } %> </select>  <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'_ it goes back to olds habbits .. So the problem may come from the the wrapper.append content

Comment: I've worked on it, and the correct version has been edited in the original post, in case someone else runs into the same problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: By the way, why did you move the script  _<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>_ on the top of the form ? I tought it was good practice to leave all the script in the bottom of the page in an EJS file

Comment: @VortexSensei - the snippet just puts it there. You're right it's good practice to load JS at the end to prevent code blocking

Answer (score 0):

Within form, all buttons are considered as a submit button.

Somehow you have to tell form that this one is not my submit button.

You have to add type="button" in button tag if type doesn't work
Add role="button"

Hope it will work !!

Comment: Adding add type="button" makes the button to no submit the post, but it does not behave as espected either.. In another application I have several buttons in a single form (form another types of script) and they do not misbehave and submit the form

Comment: If You're using an HTML5 button element then the button has a default behavior of submit, as stated in the W3 specification as seen here:[W3C HTML5 Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)